# Why is there an extra step for showing f is surjective?

Tags: functions

Let $f:\mathbb R\setminus \{-2\}\to \mathbb R\setminus \{4\}$ be a function defined by $f(x)=\dfrac{4x}{x+2}$.
Show that $f$ is surjective.

Ok so this is a pretty straightforward question, I did the necessary steps like

> > Let $y\in \mathbb R\setminus\{4\}$ such that $x=\dfrac{-2y}{y-4}$.
> >     Then,
> >
> > $\displaystyle f(x)=f\left(\frac{-2y}{y-4}\right)=y.$
> >
> > Therefore, $f$ is surjective, as there exists an $x\in \mathbb R\setminus \{-2\}$ for all  $y\in \mathbb R\setminus\{4\}$.

But my teacher said, there is another step.

Which step have I left out?

Comment: I'm almost certain Assaf's answer nails it, but why didn't you ask your teacher?

Comment: Personal reasons. Not of the teacher's fault.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to show that $x$ is in the domain, namely $x\neq -2$.

If $x$ is not in the domain of $f$ then $f$ is not defined on $x$ (even if we know that it *should* be defined), and in such case you have not shown that $y\in\operatorname{rng}(f)$ as wanted.

You should use the fact that $y\neq 4$ to argue that $x\neq -2$.

Comment: What happens if $x$ is not in the domain?

Comment: @SingaporeanDude: Then the function is not defined for that particular $x$, and therefore $y$ may not be in the range of $f$.

Comment: I see thank!@@@